# What is the output of SSCheck.Value in VB6?

Tags: vb6, controls, checkbox, custom-controls

I have third party control `SSCheck` which I found recently not supporting in my project. Maybe its DLL or OCX is corrupt or deleted. I didn't get the exact cause of that problem. Now my question is:

Which built-in control can I used to replace the `SSCheck` control? Maybe the answer is CheckBox. If CheckBox is the answer, then please suggest me the output for `SSCheck.Value` so I can adjust code accordingly.

Comment: There are good reasons for wanting to replace the SSControls (Threed32.ocx). It's not [supported on Vista or Windows 7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbrun/ms788708.aspx), although we've found it does work... But just for completeness: if you're having a "License Information for This Component Not Found" error in the VB6 IDE, there is are [known fixes](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177799) for this: [also this fix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/195353)

Answer (score 2):

The `SSCheck` control is a checkbox intended as a replacement or enhancement for the standard `CheckBox` control in the VB6 toolbox. It was provided as part of the Sheridan SSControls as threed32.ocx, which is [no longer supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbrun/ms788708.aspx). I assume this is why you're running into problems with it.

You're correct in thinking that the best solution is simply to replace these third party controls in your application with standard controls. Particularly in the case of `SSCheck`, it should be a very straightforward, almost drop-in replacement.

The `Value` property of the `SSCheck` control is a `Boolean` type, meaning it takes either "True" or "False" as indicators of its checked state. However, the `Value` property of the standard `CheckBox` control takes one of the following `Integer` values:

> 0    (`vbUnchecked`)
>   1    (`vbChecked`)
>   2    (`vbGrayed`)

which you can set either at run-time in your code (in which case, it's probably preferred that you use the provided VB constants), or at design-time in the Properties Window.

**So the only thing you'll have to do is make sure that you change anywhere in your code where you set `SSCheck.Value` to use an `Integer` (or one of the pre-defined constants) value, rather than a `Boolean` value.** For example, instead of this:

```
SSCheck1.Value = True
SSCheck2.Value = False
```

you would have this:

```
RegularCheck1.Value = vbChecked
RegularCheck2.Value = vbUnchecked
```

You will notice that the standard checkbox control looks just a little bit different than `SSCheck` when it is checked. `SSCheck` draws the check as a little X, unlike the standard Windows controls, which use an actual checkmark:

[image: comparison sample of the two checkbox controls]

Comment: +1 You may also want to change any code that *reads* the value, for clarity. For example `If check.Value Then` will still work, because `vbUnchecked` is `0`, but you might consider this clearer `If check.Value = vbChecked Then`